# .toArray(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

I have a issue with converting longitute and latitute into a array my code is like this:

```
<div id="right" class="map">

  <div id='map' class="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px;'></div>
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibGl2ZS1vbGRoYW0iLCJhIjoiY2ozbXk5ZDJ4MDAwYjMybzFsdnZwNXlmbyJ9.VGDuuC92nvPbJo-qvhryQg';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
      center: [-1.77, 52.73],
      zoom: 3

    });
    map.addControl(new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken
    }));
    map.on('click', function(e) {
      var test = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat);
      test.toArray();
      console.log(test);
      mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(test)
        .addTo(map);
    });
```

test is returning value as:

`{"lng":-2.8246875000017155,"lat":52.72999999999914}`

However, the value needs to be as:

`[-2.8246875000017155, 52.72999999999914]`

So toArray should work but I get

> Uncaught TypeError: test.toArray is not a function
>        at e. (1:181)
>        at e.Evented.fire (evented.js:87)
>        at h (bind_handlers.js:139)
>        at HTMLDivElement.s (bind_handlers.js:114)

**Edit**

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
  var test = e.lngLat;
  console.log(test);
  test.toArray();
  mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat(test)
    .addTo(map);
});
```

But now I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: And why would a regular string have a `toArray` method, there's no such thing ?

Comment: from https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglat#toarray                                              var ll = new mapboxgl.LngLat(-73.9749, 40.7736);
ll.toArray(); // = [-73.9749, 40.7736]

Comment: `var arr = [e.lngLat.lng, e.lngLat.lat]` <- like that

Comment: But you've used `JSON.stringify`, you no longer have a mapbox object, just a plain old string ?

Comment: Try `test = e.lngLat.toArray()`

Comment: see an edit plz

Comment: In your edit, you have to capture the result of calling `toArray` in a variable. Like `test = test.toArray()`.

Comment: You should be able to pass a `lngLat` object directly to `setLngLat()`

Comment: so how do you suggest doing it exactly? @charlietfl

Comment: @Przemek they mean just do `mapboxgl.Marker().setLngLat(e.lngLat).addTo(map);`

Comment: same issue 'bind'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have to create a **new** marker. If you follow the code in the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker) it should work.

Try the following modification to your code

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    new mapboxgl.Marker()
        .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
        .addTo(map);
});
```

**Edit**

Nothing will appear as a marker, you have to style that yourself as far as I'm aware, try adding this CSS to see something.

```
.mapboxgl-marker {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could try the following:

```
var longLatArray = [];
longLatArray.push(e.lng);
longLatArray.push(e.lat);
mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat(longLatArray)
    .addTo(map);
```

Comment: still same error = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Comment: Have you got a plunk that you can share?

Comment: what do you see when you log the value of e?

Comment: Looks like you might be using Marker() incorrectly: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers It looks like it needs an object, doesn't it?

Comment: @KyleMeenehan it needs to be `e.lngLat.lng` and `e.lngLat.lat`, see the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#lnglat) too. And you're looking at the wrong documentation for Marker, it's [this](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#marker), not Google.